# logging off a user when the session times out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-4, global-asax

I am creating a mvc4 application and here I am creating a cookie to give a user access to various pages depending on their roles and things. but I have different doubt. Instead of logging off people generally tend to close the browser window. So, I made the cookie not store any of the data from the login when that happens (or I think thats what happens, according to the blogs and answers Ive read so far!)

I only want 10 users to access that site at one time. So when the user closes the browser or when the session ends I want it to execute the LogOff function that keeps track of the number of people logged in and opens up that port session for use by someone else.

I tried adding session_end in the global.asax page and it just never seems to get there. and for testing purposes I had it expiring in a minutes time. But it does however go to the Session_start in the same global.asax page.

Any idea as to how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do (hoping its not silly!):
In the web.config, needed to add the timeout here to trigger session_end
`<system.web>
<sessionState mode ="InProc" timeout="10"/>
</system.web>`

Although, in the same web.config there is a timeout here, i dont know where it goes.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/SiteUsers/Logon" timeout="10" />
    </authentication>
```

If you guys have other ways to get around this, please do tell me, im all ears! Im still in the trying and testing everything phase so any help will be much appreciated :)

Thanks guys! hope this helps solve someones problem.

Comment: I would really like to know if what i've done is alright! thanks again!